# Python Try: except: else: deleting temporary variables

Tags: python, django, try-except

In my Django views.py, I potentially build around 50 derived time series for any given instance of my `Project` model; depending on its attributes. Only if each parameter required for a derived attribute is valid, I then append the label/cost/start/end to the their corresponding list.

To try and handle this, I put each calculated variable into a temporary variable and only fill the `df_` lists in the `else:` section if they all have valid values. However, this means that I'm manually clearing the temporary variables each time (`del cost`, `del start`, `del end`). I'm guessing there is a better way...?!

### views.py

```
#...

df_label=[]
df_cost=[]
df_start=[]
df_end=[]

#First potential derived elements for DataFrame
try: 
    cost=  #custom calculation here
    start= #custom calculation here
    end=   #custom calculation here
except:
    error_message.append("Warning1")
else:
    df_label.append('Label here')
    df_cost.append(cost)
    df_start.append(start)
    df_end.append(end)
    del cost
    del start
    del end

#Second potential derived elements for DataFrame
try: 
    cost=  #custom calculation here
    start= #custom calculation here
    end=   #custom calculation here
except:
    error_message.append("Warning2")
else:
    df_label.append('Label here')
    df_cost.append(cost)
    df_start.append(start)
    df_end.append(end)
    del cost
    del start
    del end

#...repeat ~50 times

#Create DataFrame from all the df_ lists
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['label']=df_label
df['cost']=df_cost
df['start']=df_start
df['end']=df_end
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to delete the variable references? The temporary variables are freed automatically when they leave scope (when your function exits). It doesn't look like your code is affected here if `cost`, `start`, and `end` remain defined.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that's the case - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Please note that the actual objects are freed, too, if they are no longer needed (the timing is not guaranteed) -- but that the objects are not "cleaned up". So if you're ever working with files, for example, you need to do clean up, first, such as closing them. In this case, it looks like the variables you're using refer to built-in numeric types, so no need to do anything special.